# Replacing PO msgstr with original using awk sed linux commands

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a language file `woocommerce-fr-Fr.po`.

I'm trying to replace the 2nd line 
**(msgstr)** with the first line **(msgid )** like this.

Before:

```
msgid "Learn how to upgrade"
msgstr "Apprenez comment mettre à jour"
```

Desired result:

```
msgid "Learn how to upgrade"
msgstr "Learn how to upgrade"
```

There are som 26000 lines so manual search and replace is not feasible.

Here is my code attempt:

```
sed 's/\([^""]*\)msgstr\(.*\)/\1lol\2/' 1.txt
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts which you have in order to solve your own problem in your post and let us know then. Also do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Doesn't matter how many lines are there, once you figure out the right script it will do them all for you.  What is the file structure? All pairs of lines msgid/msgstr or else?

Comment: Is there no `woocommerce-en-US.po` or similar file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` cannot match across newline boundaries (it's not impossible to pull off but it's nontrivial and slightly frustrating) but this is easy enough with Awk.

```
awk '$1 == "msgid" { s=$0; sub(/msgid/, "msgstr", s); print; print s; next }
    $1 == "msgstr" { next }
    1' woocommerce-fr-Fr.po >new.po
```

When we see a `msgid` we print that, then print a modified line where we have replaced `msgid` with `msgstr`. Any remaining `msgstr` lines we skip. Anything else gets passed through verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR%2{print; sub(/[^ ]+/,"msgstr"); print}' file
msgid "Learn how to upgrade"
msgstr "Learn how to upgrade"
```

Comment: This works fine if the file only contains alternating `msgid` and `msgstr` lines and nothing else (no empty lines even) but that's probably not actually the case. (Arguably the OP should have provided a better representative sample of the input file.)

Comment: There's a lot of things that **could** be different so until if/when the OP tells us otherwise I'm just assuming that the posted sample input/output is truly representative of their real data. If anythings different it'll be a trivial tweak to the script no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `sed` solution:

```
sed '/^msgid "\([^"]*\).*/{N;s//msgid "\1"\nmsgstr "\1"/;}'
```

with POSIX `sed` you need:

```
sed '/^msgid "\([^"]*\).*/{N;s//msgid "\1"\'$'\n''msgstr "\1"/;}'
```

If a line starts with `msgid`, read next line, extract the part between the first pair of `"` and output the formatted output with msgid and msgstr. Tested in [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/ConsciousSelfassuredConcentrate).